# connect APIM Basic tier with a Azure Function (premium plan) to access Vnet?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Within a vnet,i have internal APIs. They are also kept private. i now wish to make a few of them public.

Although I am aware that the APIM premium tier supports Vnet connections, the cost is simply too high. sadly

As a backend, I can see that APIM supports an Azure function. We currently have certain Azure function apps with vent connections and premium plans. It appears that I can expose my APIs within the vent for a very low cost by using the APIM basic tier in conjunction with an Azure Function. I'm curious about the costs and benefits of doing this.
any cons? on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to configure your Azure Function as a backend target for APIM. This means that when a client makes a request to your API through APIM, APIM will forward the request to your Azure Function, which will then make a request to your internal API within your VNet. The response will then be sent back to the client through APIM. Correct me if am wrong here.

This solution allows you to use the basic tier of APIM while still keeping your internal APIs within your VNet and not exposing them publicly.
However, it's important to note that the basic tier of APIM does not support VNet integration, so your Azure Function would need to be hosted outside of your VNet. This means that your Azure Function would need to make outbound calls to your internal APIs over the Internetbut This can introduce additional latency and security risks.